# Getting authenticated user informations with Django Rest Framework, JWT and Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, jwt, axios, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm building an app using DRF as a backend and Vuejs for the frontend, I've already managed to create the authentication system using JWT tokens in DRF, but I'm having a hard time trying to get the authenticated user informations. When I register the user I store, the token in local storage as

```
localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.data.token)
```

But when I try to get the user's informations sending a http get request with an authorization header I get a 401 forbidden error

```
detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Here's my code:
I set the header authorization like this with axios

`const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
if (token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =`Basic ${token}
`}`

The get request in vue

```
 getUser(){
  axios.get(this.url +'/api/auth/user/')
  .then( (response) =>{
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

My views.py

```
class UserViewSet(APIView):
permission_classes      = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
def get(self, request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', )
```

When I remove the permissions class, I get an empty username field as a response otherwise it's a 401 error as mentioned before.
I can see that the authorization header is sent in the browser.
Any solutions please?

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#Third party
'webpack_loader',
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
#Local apps
'users',
```

]

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
#Cors
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

]

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', #Oauth, JWT
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
),
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
),
'SEARCH_PARAM': 'q',
'ORDERING_PARAM': 'ordering',
```

}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

```
'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
#'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler'
'users.api.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT', # Authorization: JWT <token>
'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
```

}

```
#Cors
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default authrization header for the DRF is

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =JWT ${token}
```

Until and unless you haven't make the changes, if this still not work please provider the setting file code.

Comment: This actually gives me an error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ;). I put the Token ${token} between `` and it gives me the same 401 unauthorized error

Comment: I added my settings.py

Comment: @AliKhiti As i saw you settings file you auth token prefix is JWT so add JWT as prefix not BASIC. I have added that